# How to user action listeners

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I'm new to Swing and need some help with action listeners. I have seen them used like this example:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Do something
    }
});
```

However I want to do something more like this:

```
button.addActionListener(myFunc);

public void myFunc(ActionEvent e) 
{
   // Do something
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: *"I'm new to Swing and need some help with action listeners."* Action listeners are AWT, not Swing.  ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two possible approaches here - either you can just call your myFunc method directly from within the first example you give:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        myFunc(e);
    }
});
```

...Or you can define an inner class that implements actionlistener and then use that:

```
class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
        //Your code
    }
}

button.addActionListener(new MyActionListener());
```

On a futuristic note, when Java 8 hits the shelves (2013, so don't hold your breath) you'll be able to do this more concisely using closures.

Comment: @Thufir Not sure what you mean by "can't really use generics" - there's several cases in swing that do use generics, and I would be very surprised if closures weren't retrofitted in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to avoid additional classes you could use a reflective trampoline class. I've written a utility class for this:

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/docs/api/org/softsmithy/lib/swing/action/ReflectiveXAction.html

More to read about reflective actions: [Chapter 6.2.3, p. 73](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/performance/1st_edition/html/JPClassLoading.fm.html#11197) of the Java Series Book [Java Platform Performance Strategies and Tactics](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/performance/) by Steve Wilson and Jeff Kesselman.

Tutorial:

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/docs/tutorial/swing/action/index.html

Maven:

```
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.softsmithy.lib</groupId>  
    <artifactId>lib-core</artifactId>  
    <version>0.1</version>  
</dependency>
```

Download:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/softsmithy/files/softsmithy/v0.1/

Answer (score 3):

Quite simply:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        myFunc(e);
    }
});


public void myFunc(ActionEvent e) 
{
   // Do something
}
```

...I know it's a bit boilerplate ...but java doesn't support passing functions as parameters.

Answer (score 3):

It would only be possible if the method returned an `ActionListener`, otherwise no. Of course, it's completely valid to delegate the handling of the `ActionEvent` to a separate method.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `Java 8` *lambda expression*

```
button.addActionListener(ae -> myFunc(ae));
```

Or as an alternative to other answers, for lower versions of Java you can use an anonymous class.

```
    ActionListener myFunc = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //code
        }
    };

    button.addActionListener(myFunc);
```